# change of coefficient

Tags: calculus

i do not what I made wrong it is posible to get the transformation
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{a(k)}{z^{2 k+v+1}}\to \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{a(k-v-1)}{z^{k+1}}$$
but it seem not work I aprecciate some help
thanks

Comment: Which kind of transformation you tried? is it just a change of variable on the summed index?

Comment: what is your question ? @antonio asis

Comment: In the second summation, should it be $\frac{a(k-v-1)}{z^{2k + 1}}$?

Comment: Change the índex  but the sum must be the same thanks